# How to measure the distortion caused by a fish eye undistortion

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fisheye

I am working on a Matlab code to measure the amount of distortion effects (like aliasing) in an undistorted fish eye image.

I was able to distort and undistort an image using the division model of fisheye distortion.

I got the below image for a Siemens star after distortion [image]

I am now trying to divide the image into rings (circular sectors) based on the range of percentage of distortion per radius.

Could someone please help me out here as I am not sure as to how I can:

1) calculate the percentage of distortion/aliasing in Matlab

2) divide the image into radial sectors based on the percentage of distortion obtained via (1)

Thank you! :-)

Comment: This is a quite interesting topic. I'd like to upvote this post and keep a track of it, but have you tried anything yet? You can tell us what you have tried or thought about so far and why you couldn't make it work or why they are not solutions.

Comment: You have posted 3 very similar questions in the last week or so about measuring the fisheye distortion of images. In all cases you have asked a broad question with little or no code. Whilst code isn't compulsory, when you've asked 3 similar questions building on the same idea it becomes like you are asking people to slowly do all the code for you! Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find the differences between an un-distorted fish eye image and normal image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745777/how-to-find-the-differences-between-an-un-distorted-fish-eye-image-and-normal-im)

Comment: Do not open duplicate questions. If you're not getting the answers you want, improve the existing question.